# Openlayers 4: How to create clusters based on Feature-Attributes with different icon for each cluster?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

My situation: I have multiple different Icon Features on my map, for example two icons from Type A, six from type B and three from C in a certain extent of the map. These icons represent types of game units (persons, vehicles etc).
When I now do the clustering as described in the example, I see how many features I have and can filter them by type. However, as it is obviously still the same cluster I can only display either icon A or Icon B and not both.

Is there a way to build a cluster based on each icon type? Is this possible directly in OpenLayers? If not, can I extend that cluster to create them based on some specific attributes?

```
let clusterLayer = new VectorLayer({
    name: "clusterlayer",
    zIndex: 230,
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function (feature) {

        let size = feature.get('features').length;
        let featureArray = feature.get('features');

        let countA  = asSequence(featureArray).count(it => it.get("type") === "A");
        if (countA > 2) {


            let style = styleCache[size];
            if (!style) {
                style = //Icon StyleA
                styleCache[size] = style;
            }
            return style;
        }

        let countB = asSequence(featureArray).count(it => it.get("type") === "B");
        if (countB > 1) {
            let style = styleCache[size];
            if (!style) {
                style = //Icon StyleB
                styleCache[size] = style;
            }
            return style;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You could modify the logic to show a mixed icon if the cluster contained types 'A' and 'B' if you want to use one layer..Otherwise, different layers sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Will remember that for future use. However, in my case it was not possible, as A and B are different types which can't be mixed together. 
Futhermore the icon depends on the number of features in the cluster. So a layer for each type was my way to got and it worked.
On my initial layer I removed the features which are covered by clusters and let the cluster handle group of features of size one to avoid duplicates

Comment: Another thing I did was adding a hover event on my clustered features which displays all cluster info in a DIV tag when a mouseover occurs.  Was very handy in my app.  Good luck with your project...

Comment: I do a similar way by using a [boostrap-popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) dialog to show some feature data + the number of features

Comment: Late to the party, but I extended OL3 slightly to allow clustering based on feature type. See here : https://github.com/ojathelonius/openlayers

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this, by creating a new layer for each Cluster with a specific style. 
So I created a new Cluster and Layer for A and a new Cluster and Layer for B.